# Laravel getting data of 2 where clauses at the same time

Tags: laravel

I need help to find out my mistake in code below:

```
public function finderfunction(Request $request) {

    // get array of categories that signed to finder (1,2,3)
    $finder = Finder::with('categories')->get();
    $catid = [];
    foreach($finder as $findd){
      foreach($findd->categories as $finddcat){
        $catid[] = $finddcat->id;
      }
    }
    //get products with those categories (1,2,3) (first where)
    $results = Product::where('category_id', $catid)
    //get products with those categories and same sku's (second where)
    ->where('sku', $request->input('brand_id'))
      ->groupBy('products.sku')
      ->get();
     return view('front.finder', compact('results'));
  }
```

As you see I commented in my code above, this is what I try to achieve:

1. My Finder model has assigned categories id's like `1,2,3`
2. Then I try to get all products included of those categories `1,2,3`
3. Then I filter them once more to get products of same `sku` between them

[image: screen1]

## Issue

During my testing process I found out that if I replace static category id with `$catid` in `$results = Product::where('category_id', $catid)` I can get my results but while i'm using same code as above no result will return back, `I get my custom message for those time that no result can be found.`

Any idea?

Comment: Just a note; To get your array of category ids, you can use the pluck function like this: `$catId = Finder::with('categories')->get()->pluck('categories.*.id')->flatten()->toArray();`

Comment: @ChinLeung thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute your code using **whereIn** like this code `Product::whereIn('category_id', $catid)`. Hope you will get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks it's working but half way, now if i have 3 products in all my 3 categories but with same sku it only shows one of them.

Comment: why you need to use groupBy? give another shot after removing it, hope you will get your desired result.

Comment: I don't! I just needed to be sure that my results will relay on sku's and not category id's

Comment: If you use where like this, it should work like your provided image. At first, it will filter on basis of your WhereIn clause, then sku. It will not skip sku matching condition.

Comment: yes i was testing it while you commenting and it seems i didn't need to group them. appreciate your help. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Your $catid variable is an array. You can not pass an array as parameter into eloquent where. You can pass an array as

```
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
           ->get();
```

Secondly, Check if your $catid successfully gain value or not.

Thirdly, To write multiple where conditions, u can pass it as an array such as -

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status', '=', '1'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

see this link for further help.